# Retrofit getting response null @post method

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2

Actually, in **Retrofit** I am trying pass parameters and I am expecting output. 
But here it is showing response as null. Here is the code that I'm trying but isn't working:

**APIClient.java**

```
class APIClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://xxxxxxx:xxxx/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

//Root URL of our web service

//Strings to bind with intent will be used to send data to other activity
public static final String KEY_company_ID = "org_video";
public static final String KEY_news_NAME = "category_name";
public static final String KEY_likes_PRICE = "file_size";
public static final String KEY_url_image = "org_thumbnail";

Button mCheck;
//List view to show data
private ListView listView;
private View parentView;
//List of type books this list will store type Book which is our data model
private List<Company> companys;
private CompanyAdapter adapter;
CompanyAPI apiInterface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mCheck = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);


    /**
     * Array List for Binding Data from JSON to this List
     */
   // companys = new ArrayList<>();

    parentView = findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
    //Initializing the listview
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewBooks);

    mCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                    loginRetrofit2Api("Onnet CMS");

        }
    });
    //Calling the method that will fetch data
   //getCompanyDetails();

    //Setting onItemClickListener to listview
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

private void loginRetrofit2Api(String userId) {
    final Company comp = new Company(userId);

    apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(CompanyAPI.class);
    Log.e("apiInterface",""+apiInterface);
    Call<Company> call1 = apiInterface.getOutput("OnnetCMS");
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<Company>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Company> call, Response<Company> response) {
            Company loginResponse = response.body();

            Log.e("response", "Response 1 --> " + loginResponse);
            if (loginResponse != null) {
                Log.e("response", "getUserId          -->  " + loginResponse.getCompany());
                Log.e("response", "getFirstName       -->  " + loginResponse.getUrl());
                Log.e("response", "getLastName        -->  " + loginResponse.getName());
                Log.e("response", "getProfilePicture  -->  " + loginResponse.getNews());


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Company> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onFailure called ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            call.cancel();
        }
    });
}
```

**CompanyAPI.java**

```
public interface CompanyAPI {

/*Retrofit get annotation with our URL
   And our method that will return us the list ob Book
*/
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/cms/contents/reqGetContentsInfoList.on")
Call<Company> getOutput(@Field("com_id") String comId);
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "result_msg": "SUCCESS",
    "content_list":
    [
        {
            "org_video": "iOT.mp4",
            "end_date": "2018-07-21 12:12:34.0",
            "file_path": "/var/www/html/contents/",
            "category_name": "E-learning",
            "enctrs_stat": 0,
            "cnt_id": 528,
            "auth": 99,
            "thumbnail_file": "http://106.51.64.251:180/contents/playVideo.png",
            "duration_sec": 0,
            "file_size": 91007457,
            "org_thumbnail": "http://106.51.64.251:180/contents/playVideo.png",
            "category_id": 176,
            "enable": 0,
            "hit_count": 0,
            "start_date": "2017-07-21 12:12:34.0"
        },
        {
            "org_video": "BigData.mp4",
            "end_date": "2018-07-21 10:48:12.0",
            "file_path": "/var/www/html/contents/",
            "category_name": "Demo",
            "enctrs_stat": 0,
            "cnt_id": 527,
            "auth": 99,
            "thumbnail_file": "http://106.51.64.251:180/contents/playVideo.png",
            "duration_sec": 0,
            "file_size": 3808501,
            "org_thumbnail": "http://106.51.64.251:180/contents/playVideo.png",
            "category_id": 198,
            "enable": 0,
            "hit_count": 0,
            "start_date": "2017-07-21 10:48:12.0"
        },
        {
            "org_video": "What is IoT-.mp4",
            "end_date": "2018-07-21 10:05:14.0",
            "file_path": "/var/www/html/contents/",
            "category_name": "E-learning",
            "enctrs_stat": 0,
            "cnt_id": 526,
            "auth": 99,
            "thumbnail_file": "http://106.51.64.251:180/contents/playVideo.png",
            "duration_sec": 0,
            "file_size": 10455459,
            "org_thumbnail": "http://106.51.64.251:180/contents/playVideo.png",
            "category_id": 176,
            "enable": 0,
            "hit_count": 0,
            "start_date": "2017-07-21 10:05:14.0"
        },
        {
            "org_video": "IoT-Prelims Current Affairs.mp4",
            "end_date": "2018-07-21 09:54:44.0",
            "file_path": "/var/www/html/contents/",
            "category_name": "E-learning",
            "enctrs_stat": 0,
            "cnt_id": 523,
            "auth": 99,
            "thumbnail_file": "http://106.51.64.251:180/contents/playVideo.png",
            "duration_sec": 0,
            "file_size": 8134193,
            "org_thumbnail": "http://106.51.64.251:180/contents/playVideo.png",
            "category_id": 176,
            "enable": 0,
            "hit_count": 0,
            "start_date": "2017-07-21 09:54:44.0"
        },
        {
            "org_video": "IoT-Architecture 4 Beginners.mp4",
            "end_date": "2018-07-21 09:47:06.0",
            "file_path": "/var/www/html/contents/",
            "category_name": "E-learning",
            "enctrs_stat": 0,
            "cnt_id": 522,
            "auth": 99,
            "thumbnail_file": "http://106.51.64.251:180/contents/playVideo.png",
            "duration_sec": 0,
            "file_size": 91007457,
            "org_thumbnail": "http://106.51.64.251:180/contents/playVideo.png",
            "category_id": 176,
            "enable": 0,
            "hit_count": 0,
            "start_date": "2017-07-21 09:47:06.0"
        },
        {
            "org_video": "Advantages of e-Learning.mp4",
            "end_date": "2018-07-21 09:43:05.0",
            "file_path": "/var/www/html/contents/",
            "category_name": "E-learning",
            "enctrs_stat": 0,
            "cnt_id": 521,
            "auth": 99,
            "thumbnail_file": "http://106.51.64.251:180/contents/playVideo.png",
            "duration_sec": 0,
            "file_size": 6022401,
            "org_thumbnail": "http://106.51.64.251:180/contents/playVideo.png",
            "category_id": 176,
            "enable": 0,
            "hit_count": 0,
            "start_date": "2017-07-21 09:43:05.0"
        },
        {
            "org_video": "6 Trends in E-learning.mp4",
            "end_date": "2018-07-21 09:42:55.0",
            "file_path": "/var/www/html/contents/",
            "category_name": "E-learning",
            "enctrs_stat": 0,
            "cnt_id": 520,
            "auth": 99,
            "thumbnail_file": "http://106.51.64.251:180/contents/playVideo.png",
            "duration_sec": 0,
            "file_size": 6152424,
            "org_thumbnail": "http://106.51.64.251:180/contents/playVideo.png",
            "category_id": 176,
            "enable": 0,
            "hit_count": 0,
            "start_date": "2017-07-21 09:42:55.0"
        }
    ],
    "result_code": "SG02S200"
}
```

This is the response I am getting from rest API.

**Company.java**

This the model class of company.

```
public class Company {

@SerializedName("org_video")
@Expose
private String company;
@SerializedName("category_name")
@Expose
private String news;
@SerializedName("file_size")
@Expose
private int likes;

@SerializedName("result_msg")
public String ResponseCode;
@SerializedName("category_id")
public String ResponseMessage;

public String getResponseCode() {
    return ResponseCode;
}

public void setResponseCode(String responseCode) {
    ResponseCode = responseCode;
}

public String getResponseMessage() {
    return ResponseMessage;
}

public void setResponseMessage(String responseMessage) {
    ResponseMessage = responseMessage;
}

@SerializedName("duration_sec")

@Expose
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

@SerializedName("org_thumbnail")
@Expose
private String url;

public String getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(String company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public String getNews() {
    return news;
}

public void setNews(String news) {
    this.news = news;
}

public int getLikes() {
    return likes;
}

public void setLikes(int likes) {
    this.likes = likes;

}

public Company(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Comment: If the above one is a response when you call the api. then what is this line for `loginResponse.getCompany()` , 'loginResponse.getUrl()'

Comment: ok but I didn't rename them properly actually I tried same code for another api so that I didn't rename exactly .

Comment: Can you post your **Company** model class

Comment: Yes now you check I have updated.

Comment: You are using Gson to parse it. So you should make your model class according to it. Wait I will post the model class for your response.

Comment: yes please thanks a lot

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs have you posted the model class for my response

Comment: Posted. Try now.

Comment: where you have posted

Comment: refresh the page or go to this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45771400/5558150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**//  1. Create ContentModel class like Below**

```
public class ContentModel {

    @SerializedName("result_msg")
    public String result_msg;

    @SerializedName("org_video")
    public String org_video;

    @SerializedName("end_date")
    public String end_date;

    @SerializedName("file_path")
    public String file_path;

    @SerializedName("category_name")
    public String category_name;

    @SerializedName("enctrs_stat")
    public String enctrs_stat;

    @SerializedName("cnt_id")
    public int cnt_id;

    @SerializedName("auth")
    public int auth;

    @SerializedName("thumbnail_file")
    public String thumbnail_file;

    @SerializedName("duration_sec")
    public String duration_sec;

    @SerializedName("file_size")
    public String file_size;

    @SerializedName("org_thumbnail")
    public String org_thumbnail;

    @SerializedName("category_id")
    public int category_id;

    @SerializedName("enable")
    public String enable;

    @SerializedName("hit_count")
    public String hit_count;

    @SerializedName("start_date")
    public String start_date;

}
```

**// 2. Create ContentJsonModel class like Below**

```
public class ContentJsonModel {

    @SerializedName("result_msg")
    public String result_msg;

    @SerializedName("content_list")
    public List<ContentModel> content_list;

    @SerializedName("result_code")
    public String result_code;
}
```

**// 3. setup Rest API**

```
public interface CompanyAPI {

/*Retrofit get annotation with our URL
   And our method that will return us the list ob Book
*/
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("cms/contents/reqGetContentsInfoList.on")
Call<ContentJsonModel> getOutput(@Field("com_id") String comId);

}
```

**// And now Finally call it on Main Class**

```
private void loginRetrofit2Api(String userId) {

  Call<ContentJsonModel> call1 = APIClient.getClient().create(CompanyAPI.class).getOutput(userId);
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<ContentJsonModel>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ContentJsonModel> call, Response<ContentJsonModel> response) {

        // All the content_data will be stored in the list
            List<ContentModel> contentModel = response.body().content_list;

            //now you can get single values like this 
             for(ContentModel model : contentModel){


             }



        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ContentJsonModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onFailure called ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
    });
}
```

Comment: but parameters are like that ,{"com_id"="Onnet CMS"}. I tried with your answer but still getting null

Comment: / doesn't matter in retrofit. and also space will be replaced %20 in retrofit. https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Field.html

Comment: Have you Called like  @POST("cms/contents/reqGetContentsInfoList.on")

Comment: Have you checked my updated answer? And if its not working then can you show your Company Model class

Comment: huhhh.. the main problem with your Model class the response you are getting from Api is different from Your Model Class

Comment: Ho.. is it ?? any naming mistake or some other

Comment: Are you sure is it POST request?

Comment: @ Mounika12  Check my updated answer. I hope it will helpful for you :)

Comment: @shahid17june I tried but it is showing nullpointerexception at iterator of contentmodel

Comment: I am getting result code SG02E500 what does it mean

Answer (score 0):

Does your **apiInterface** variable value is same as

`CompanyAPI apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(CompanyAPI.class);`

Comment: I am not getting exactly. Can you pls tell brief

Comment: before `Call<Company> call1 = apiInterface.getOutput("Onnet CMS");` line you need **apiInterface** variable value

Comment: when I am debugging it shows 
       apiInterface = retrofit2.Retrofit$1@2cfe93b0

Comment: I got like this, E/apiInterface: retrofit2.Retrofit$1@31480872

Comment: did you get it after adding `CompanyAPI apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(CompanyAPI.class);` line to your code?

Comment: yes After I added this line then I am getting that output

Comment: can you update your MainActivity.java code so that i will check?

Comment: in `loginRetrofit2Api("Onnet CMS");` line it has **Onnet CMS** and in `Call<Company> call1 = apiInterface.getOutput("OnnetCMS");` it is **OnnetCMS** with no space. Is it the same userId you want to access?